# iPod keeps randomly crashing on sync

Tags: sync, crash, ipod-touch

My iPod Touch 2G keeps randomly crashing when syncing with my home computer. Here are the symptoms:

- After the sync, if I go to my music on the iPod, nothing appears. This is how I know the sync failed.
- When I try to re-sync, it says it can't be read and needs to be restored.
- I usually have no luck restoring from my machine. It fails repeated after many attempts. If I go to another machine it restores fine.
- After restoring, I sync with my computer. It takes hours, but it syncs successfully.

I haven't found any rhyme or reason as to when or why it crashes. It can go weeks without doing it, then crash on back to back days.

I suspect it has something to do with my computer, but moving my library to a new machine is not an option right now. Any idea what's going on, or how I can prevent it?

Comment: Are you using the same sync cable on both machines?  I've had those cables go bad before.

Comment: I've tried several different cables, always the same results unfortunately.

Comment: Rats.  (Please enter at least 15 characters.)

Comment: I'll assume that you have also tried using different USB ports on the problem machine, and that you are either using Mac OSX or have re-installed iTunes on your Windows box.

Comment: Yep, different USB ports, iTunes reinstalled (Windows XP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What else you do have on you USB ports? Is it plugged into a non-powered hub?

I had a problem with an iPod Mini that would screw up randomly on sync. Moving it off the non-powered hub to the built in port on my computer fixed that problem.

Comment: I tried that, but it hasn't seemed to have any affect. However, I wouldn't be surprised if it were related to the problem, i.e. the computer itself having some random USB blips that are confusing the iPod.

Answer (score 0):

You have already tried the solution I was going to suggest, but I have heard of this problem before. My brother in law had a similar problem and he ended up bricking 5 iPhones (all replaced by Apple).

If everything is still under warranty you should probably take it to an apple store and reproduce the problem with them. When my brother in law did it, the geniuses didn't believe it until they reproduced it themselves, bricking another 2 phones in the process.

Completely Removing and replacing iTunes fixed it for him, but I see you have already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your iPod in Disk Mode, and running `chkdsk /r` (if you're on Windows) or using Disk Utility to repair the permissions / repair disk (if you're on OSX)

Once you've repaired permissions, can you do a restore and a resync, and if so, is performance better / more stable?

Comment: iPod Touch lacks a disk mode unless you do a Jail Break on it. That would not work.

Comment: I missed the fact that it was an iPod touch. My bad. This does work for for iPods that do have a disk mode however.

Answer (score -1):

Most problems with iPods and iPhones will be fixed by doing a simple restore in iTunes. Just click your iPod under devices on the left, and hit restore

[image]

This should solve any of your problems. It is very rare that you would have a hardware defect that would be causing it. If you do, just return it back to Apple as it is still under warranty (assuming you have not voided it).

Comment: gfrizzle states in the question he already tried restoring: "# I usually have no luck restoring from my machine. It fails repeated after many attempts. If I go to another machine it restores fine.
# After restoring, I sync with my computer. It takes hours, but it syncs successfully."

Comment: @Jared: "This should solve any of your problems. It is very rare that you would have a hardware defect that would be causing it. If you do, just return it back to Apple as it is still under warranty (assuming you have not voided it)."